# how to search web content with blobs or long strings

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, full-text-search

According to https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/datamodeling:

> The datastore supports two value types for storing text: short text strings up to 500 >characters in length, and long text strings up to one megabyte in length. Short strings are >indexed and can be used in query filter conditions and sort orders. Long strings are not >indexed and cannot be used in filter conditions or sort orders.

This is a problem for me, because my site will be text heavy with government documents. The whole point of the site is to make these documents accessible, i.e, searchable. Then I also read at : https://developers.google.com/appengine/training/fts_intro/ :

> Search can query any data, so long as that data is described by a search document.

It is not at all clear to me that I can in fact have a full text search of my large text field documents, because a search object is apparently not identical to a datastore entity. So, my question:
If you have a large block of text, and you can’t get it indexed, filtered, or sorted, can it be found using the search api, or does the no index rule apply here as well? And if so, then how does one use GAE effectively with large text documents?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like [django-watson](https://github.com/etianen/django-watson) for full text searching.

Sample model code:

```
import watson

class Document (models.Model):

    #: Title for the item
    title = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=False, 
        help_text="Document title")

    #: Description for the item.
    description = models.TextField(blank=False, 
        help_text="Description of the document")

    #: Document text for searching
    doc_text = models.TextField(blank=False, 
        help_text="Searchable document text")

watson.register(Document.objects.all(), fields=("title", "description", 
    "doc_text"))
```

Comment: "django-watson uses MySQL's full text indexes on a MyISAM table to provide good search capabilities." https://github.com/etianen/django-watson/wiki/database-support. Innodb is now the default MySQL storage engine and has been for a while, I think.

Comment: @MalikA.Rumi I use Postgres normally. The project very well could be out of date for MySQL.

Comment: @Lipis You raise another issue I also wondered about: can you bring in competing, non-Google search technologies to an app engine product? Maybe that has to be a separate/new question posting.

Comment: As long as you are doing stuff the app engine way you can achieve it.. many of the current solutions are using the file system it self.. which will not work.. But if you are using cloud storage or MySQL or anything else for the solution I don't see a reason why it shouldn't..

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your question is. Searching on long text fields is *exactly* what the [full-text search API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/) is for.

The FTS service is not directly related to the datastore, which is why that page you quote talks about "documents". You programmatically create a search document, potentially using some or all of the datastore fields, and you can then search on that.

Comment: This API is for the datastore. I have decided to go with MySQL/Google Cloud SQL. The datastore has a number of search limitations that I don't think will work for me.

Comment: No. Once again, the FTS API is completely separate from the data store. You create documents from any source at all. But I guess it's up to you.